# Is it possible to set variable in variable with ansible?

Tags: ansible

For example, set a username for each different service as

```yaml
    - name: Add the user 'user_xxx' with password
      ansible.builtin.user:
        name: "{{ user_name_{{svc_name}} }}"
        password: "{{ user_password_{{svc_name}} | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

In order to set dynamic values to `name` and `password`, use thess variables in `group_vars`:

```
user_name_a
user_name_b
user_name_c
user_password_a
user_password_b
user_password_c
```

But want to read `a`, `b`, `c` from an environment variable as:

```sh
export SERVICE_NAME=a
```

playbook:

```yaml
vars:
  svc_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'SERVICE_NAME') }}"
```

Then compile 2 kinds of variables together to make a final value.

When I tried to do it, I got

```
fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '{'. String: {{ user_name_{{svc_name}} }}"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, given the *group_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
user_name_a: userA
user_name_b: userB
user_name_c: userC
user_password_a: psswdA
user_password_b: psswdB
user_password_c: psswdC
```

the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    svc_name: "{{ lookup('env', 'SERVICE_NAME') }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "name: {{ lookup('vars', 'user_name_' ~ svc_name) }},
              pswd: {{ lookup('vars', 'user_password_' ~ svc_name) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> SERVICE_NAME=b ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: 'name: userB, pswd: psswdB'

  ...
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is. `lookup` is the right solution for this issue.